# How to use Variable value for another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have tried the below code and  getting results s i mentioned below.

code:

```
yday_mnth = '201905'
b = yday_mnth
x = 'yday_mnth'
print b
print x
```

Output here is as below:

```
201905
yday_mnth
```

Which means for `b` am getting value as `201905` however for `x` I'am getting `yday_mnth` 
as its a `string` 
however is there any way to convert the `x` to print value 
of `yday_mnth`? i.e `201905`

Comment: If you want `x` to have the same value as `yday_mnth`, then you can simply do `x = yday_mnth`... But I suspect you know this already, because that's exactly how you defined `b`. Can you elaborate a little more on your use case?

Comment: remove the quotes of `'yday_mnth'`

Comment: I think Naveen might be looking for the `eval` function in this case. In your example, `eval('yday_mnth')` would do the trick - however, using `eval` is generally not recommended, so please use with caution.

Comment: I suspect what you're really saying is 'I don't know what value x has until runtime. It could be "yday_mnth" or "foobar" or "baz", and in each of these cases I want x's value to become the value of whatever variable it's holding the name of'. This is an antipattern commonly known as "variable variables" and it's almost always a bad idea. Related reading: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/953482)

Comment: `globals()[x]` Be gentle :) Depending on the scope, ofcourse